# How to add Date Picker in Horizontal paging scroll view in angular Js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datepicker

I am the beginner in angularjs. I have created PhoneGap application for using date picker I need month and date in horizontal but I have created date picker demo it is in picker type but I need this type picker it shows in image.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' ;
  }

  

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      // var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        // var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div>
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzql9.png]

Answer (score 1):

use **Bootstrap Date Paginator**
A full list of dependencies required for the bootstrap-datepaginator to function correctly.

```
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Required Javascript -->
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap-datepaginator.js"></script>
```

more details [Bootstrap Date Paginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator)